# Does the inertia of a beam section include the material density?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, applied-mechanics, beam

Sorry but I'm a little rusty.  When solving a beam of any type of section, must the density be included in the moment of inertia of the section?

For example, if I see Navier's formula, I would say that it is not needed, but it seems strange to me

For example, the inertia of a filled circle is:

$J = \frac{\pi D^4}{64}$

and the density does not appear.

Comment: Aren't you confusing 'moment of inertia' with 'second axial moment of area'? Check the [ISO 80000-4, Table 1, items 4-7 and 4-21.1](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:80000:-4:ed-2:v1:en).

Comment: I think you are right. The beam theory, and thus Navier formula, is based on second axial moment of area. So, it is based only on geometric proprieties and it doesn't involve material. Did I guess right? No many people apply the distinction you propose, but I think it is important. Do you think I catched your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused with the "(mass) moment of inertia" and the "second moment of area" as both have the same terms, moment and inertia, in the name, and both are denoted the same - "I".

- The "(mass) moment of inertia", also known as the "rotational inertia", and sometimes as the "angular mass", measures the extent to which an object resists rotational acceleration about a particular axis, and is the rotational analogue to mass (which determines an object's resistance to linear acceleration). [Here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51885/has-the-inertia-of-a-beam-section-to-incluse-the-material-density) is a list of the equations for various situations.
- The "second moment of area", also known as the "area moment of inertia", is a geometrical property of an area (cross-sectional area) of a given shape, which reflects how its points are distributed with regard to an arbitrary axis. In "Structural Engineering", it is an important property used in the calculation of the structural elements' deflection and the calculation of stress caused by a moment applied to the element. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_second_moments_of_area) is a list of equations of various shapes.

Note that the equation you stated is the "second moment of area of a circle". You should avoid denoting it as "J", which generally represents the torsional constant of an area.

Comment: Thank you for the very complete answer. In some notes or textbook, the author assumes "unitary density" for the second moment of area. This assumption, that is an error, confused me. Thank you again for your clarification.

Comment: You are welcome. It is correct that the distribution of mass is **not a concern** of the "second moment of area", which is purely based on the geometry of the shape in concern.